# How can I make my PHPUnit tests more succinct, less long?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

The PHPUnit tests I'm writing for my web application are killing me with their length and their opaqueness. It seems there's an order of magnitude more code in the tests than in the code they're testing.

For example, say my web site has a `CatController` object on which is this method:

```
public function addCat(Default_Model_Cat $cat)
{
    $workflow = $this->catWorkflowFactory->create(array($this->serviceExecutor));
    $workflow->addCat($cat);
}
```

The unit test I would have to create to test it thoroughly would be something like this:

```
public function testAddCat()
{
    $cat = $this->getMockBuilder('Default_Model_Cat')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $controller = $this->getMockBuilder('CatController')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(array('none'))
        ->getMock();
    $workflow = $this->getMockBuilder('Default_Model_Workflow_Cat')
        ->setMethods(array('addCat'))
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $workflow->expects($this->once())
        ->method('addCat')
        ->with($cat);
    $controller->serviceExecutor = $this->getMockBuilder('ServiceExecutor')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $controller->catWorkflowFactory = $this->getMockBuilder('Factory')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(array('create'))
        ->getMock();
    $controller->catWorkflowFactory->expects($this->once())
        ->method('create')
        ->with($controller->serviceExecutor)
        ->will($this->returnValue($workflow));
    $controller->addCat($cat);
}
```

Is there any syntax I can use to make unit tests shorter and easier to read? For example, rather than saying "this object is a mock on which this method will be called, and when this method is called on it then it will be called once with this argument and will return this value" it would be nice if I could just say something like `once(object->method(argument)) => $returnvalue`.

Comment: just a thought: i'm sure this doesn't apply to other people but when my unit tests seem like they're getting ridiculous i often discover the issue is suboptimal code design/separation on my part :)

Answer (score 2):

The more you can design your classes to be usable within unit tests without needing to be mocked, the less mocking code you'll need to write. But for the above example my first reaction is that this method doesn't need a unit test because it isn't really performing any logic and won't change after being written.

That being said, assuming you will need a workflow instance in other methods of this class, extract the code that creates it to a new method. This allows you to mock that method for each test and only have the longer mocking in the one test.

For example, if you also had a `removeCat()` method it would look like this:

```
public function addCat(Default_Model_Cat $cat) {
    $this->createWorkflow()->addCat($cat);
}

public function removeCat(Default_Model_Cat $cat) {
    $this->createWorkflow()->removeCat($cat);
}

public function createWorkflow() {
    return $this->catWorkflowFactory->create(array($this->serviceExecutor));
}
```

The above methods are supremely short and really don't need unit tests, but they'll be a little shorter now:

```
public function testAddCat() {
    $cat = $this->getMockBuilder('Default_Model_Cat')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $controller = $this->getMockBuilder('CatController')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(array('createWorkflow'))
        ->getMock();
    $workflow = $this->getMockBuilder('Default_Model_Workflow_Cat')
        ->setMethods(array('addCat'))
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $controller->expects($this->once())
        ->method('createWorkflow')
        ->will($this->returnValue($workflow));
    $workflow->expects($this->once())
        ->method('addCat')
        ->with($cat);
    $controller->addCat($cat);
}
```

If you have many such methods in the controller, you can create helper methods in your test case to create the mocks. Finally, do you really need to disable the original constructors on your mocks? I *rarely* need to do that myself.

Comment: I heavily disagree with "But for the above example my first reaction is that this method doesn't need a unit test because it isn't really performing any logic and won't change after being written." It's dispatching calls to other methods. That pretty much everything a method should do and there should be a test to make sure the right methods are dispatched to with the right parameters. To add on to that I'd also rather not mock the SUT without any specific need just to easy testing. Imho thats a workaround for legacy not a good practice for new code. Just my few points. Good answer though :)

Comment: Ideally the test would use real objects instead of mocks and simply verify that the category was added. But the few things that can go wrong with the method will be pretty obvious up front. Any refactoring will require a *serious* amount of test refactoring with marginal gain. Striving for 100% code coverage can become more of a burden than a help, and short methods make it less necessary. This is one of the big lessons from *[Clean Code](http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882)*.

Comment: For me the "Clean Code" book is about having small descriptive named methods and striving for 100% code coverage with nicely readable code. For me mocked SUTs are always a WTF factor and have very few use cases (f.e. working around 'current time' issues without introducing calendar objects). In the original sample at hand I don't see any need for mocking the SUT so I won't introduce one. I also fail to see how your approach here reduces test adoption time when refactoring. 3-4 depending mocks always take time to adapt, especially when hard to read

Comment: One of the tenants in the book is that tests that are more complicated than the code they test are a code smell and should be avoided--either by refactoring so you don't need tests or rethinking your design. For example, I don't write tests for getters and setters. As I said I wouldn't write a test for the above method, but the OP wants one and used mocks in their example. I assume they need to use mocks because the real classes cannot be constructed in the unit test. Given that, the above is how I would mock it.

Comment: David, your original reply goes against two fundamental precepts I've been taught about unit testing: (1) Write unit tests for all code that does anything (and if code doesn't do anything, then delete it). (2) Unit tests should only test units, the smallest pieces of code testable by themselves; don't call a constructor unless you're specifically (and only) testing that constructor. (Do you agree with these rules, or am I off the beaten path here?)

Comment: I do like your idea to pull my workflow-creation code into its own method; that will help simplify things in the original code as well as in the unit tests.  I still am a little skeptical of that idea because it'll result in one-line methods, and I don't like one-line methods (is this one line being used in a single place or in twenty places?), but I think that's a necessary evil.

Comment: @BrianKendig - The unit is the class/component being tested. When testing a task scheduler that stores future tasks in a queue, you need a queue during the test. You are testing its interactions with other components. When you can verify the test results using the real components, this is preferred as testing will be easier. The test code can also be a good example for how to use the class in the real world. Since you'll never use mocking in production code, it makes sense to avoid it unless there's no other way.

Comment: To clarify, while each unit test is designed to test a single method as the unit, that doesn't mean you cannot call other methods on the object to set up the state being tested. For example, `testRemoveLastItem()` in `StackTest` requires a stack with a single item. Better to use `Stack::add()` than poke data into the stack somehow or mock `isEmpty()` to falsely return `true` for the empty stack. Calling the class's constructor should only be avoided when you either a) need to mock a method called by the constructor or b) cannot build the objects the constructor requires.

Comment: @David, I have to respectfully disagree with you here. You're describing integration tests, not unit tests; and in your example, one failure in Stack::add() could cause a large number of tests to fail and leave you having to hunt for the piece of code at fault. When testing a task scheduler that stores future tasks in a queue, you don't need an actual queue; you just need to make sure your scheduler makes the appropriate calls which, elsewhere, are tested to make sure they add items to the queue. But this goes outside my original question, so I will probably start a new question on this.

Comment: @DavidHarkness Wait, what ?? I've always thought unit tests should be testing ONE thing, with everything else around "acting" as if it's working. So when one test fails, that means only this very thing tested failed to work, not something in the "everything else around".

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `CatController` object you shouldn't be mocking it in the test if at all possible. You want to test that class so use the real class.

You can get rid of all the `"setMethod"` calls. By default **all** methods will be mocked and that is what you want.

There are other mocking libraries that make mocking less lines of code like `Phake` and `Mockery` that some people like but I don't have too much personal experience with it.

What strikes me as a little odd is that you set the mocks using public properties. I would have expected those to go into the Controllers constructor.

#### Given that thats your method that could be done:

```
public function testAddCat()
{
    $cat = $this->getMockBuilder('Default_Model_Cat')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $workflow = $this->getMockBuilder('Default_Model_Workflow_Cat')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $workflow->expects($this->once())
        ->method('addCat')
        ->with($cat);

    $controller = new CatController(/*if you need params here pass them!*/);
    // You can use this to avoid mocking the object if you want
    // If your tests are more of a usage doc maybe don't
    $controller->serviceExecutor = "My fake Executor";

    $controller->catWorkflowFactory = $this->getMockBuilder('Factory')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $controller->catWorkflowFactory->expects($this->once())
        ->method('create')
        ->with(array("My fake Executor"))
        ->will($this->returnValue($workflow));

    $controller->addCat($cat);
}
```

---

#### Let's take some common stuff into setup

Just to get each function a little nicer to read lets take out the default mocks into setup.

```
public function setUp() {

    $this->controller = new CatController(/*if you need params, pass them!*/);
    $this->serviceExecutor = $this->getMockBuilder('ServiceExecutor')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $this->controller->serviceExecutor = $this->serviceExecutor;
    $this->cat = $this->getMockBuilder('Default_Model_Cat')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $this->workflow = $this->getMockBuilder('Default_Model_Workflow_Cat')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $this->controller->catWorkflowFactory = $this->getMockBuilder('Factory')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
}
```

and the method:

```
public function testAddCat()
{
    $this->workflow->expects($this->once())
        ->method('addCat')
        ->with($this->cat);

    $this->controller->catWorkflowFactory->expects($this->once())
        ->method('create')
        ->with(array($this->serviceExecutor))
        ->will($this->returnValue($this->workflow));

    $this->controller->addCat($cat);
}
```

It's still not *really* pretty but we split it up into more manageable chunks.

Setup creates all the fake objects but they don't do anything (so they don't fail any test and the setup time should be negligence

while the tests focuses on describing what should happen.

---

In general I'd say "if it is that complicated to use the class maybe it's a good thing the tests show that a lot of stuff needs to be done". If thats a problem maybe change the class. The production could that uses it will also have a hard time setting everything right. But many frameworks/approaches make Controllers 'special' in that regard so you know best :)

Comment: Good call on not needing to call setMethods() every time. I got into the habit because, too often, I would forget to call that when I mocked the controller, and then when I called the method I'm testing on the controller, I would actually be calling the mock that returns NULL. By the way, I mock the controller because I don't want to call its constructor unless I'm specifically testing the constructor (see my comment above).

Comment: I don't like using setUp() calls; in my experience if I pull a lot of code into a setUp() that means either there's a lot of duplicated code in my SUT, or else setUp() is setting things up that most tests won't need. By the way, what do you mean about my setting the mocks using public properties - what should go into the constructor instead?

Comment: @BrianKendig If your SUT needs 3-4 other objects to work properly (as in construction/setup) I don't see any issue with creating those in the setUp. That is what it's usually there for. To create an object instance of your SUT. Now if it complicated to set up your SUT thats another issue. To the other point: Accessing public properties from the outside feels like another form of setter injection http://misko.hevery.com/2009/02/19/constructor-injection-vs-setter-injection/ to me. But if thats good there or not you know best :)